# Karma dosen't generate lcov.info

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

When I run `ng test --watch=false --code-coverage` I don't receive an lcov.info file...
Anyone could have an idea? a feedback or experience about this issue please ?
my karma.conf.js

module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

```
// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  '*/*/*.spec.ts',
  '*.spec.ts',
  '*.ts'
],


// list of files / patterns to exclude
exclude: [
  '*.component.ts',
  'component.ts'
],
preprocessors: {
},
reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
coverageReporter: {
  type : 'lcovonly',
  dir : 'coverage/'
},
// web server port
port: 9876,
colors: true,
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
autoWatch: true,
browsers: ['Chrome', 'ChromeHeadless', 'PhantomJS'],
singleRun: false,
concurrency: Infinity
```

})
}

I tried different possibilities but nothing work